# IOS apps don't publish using Flash CS6 - stuck at 00:05

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

I am trying to publish a single square with no code. I have installed the update for flash pro CS6, and I am using AIR for IOS 3.4

Every time I try to publish it gets stuck at 00:05

I also sometimes get an error saying, "please make sure there is enough space on the device"

It is a brand new ipad...

I also have the ipad registered on the provisioning profile.

Comment: downvotes for no reason? No one has suggestions?

Comment: This is very confusing. I have published on android, but Apple has all these unnecessary hoops you need to jump though. In the CS6 publish settings under where you put in the provisioning profile, is the App ID the name of your app (like NameIpad2) or is it the 10 digit string of numbers and letters? (like XK285EN62V.com.goldenlion.nameipad2)

Comment: ugh. This is so embarrassing that I consider myself a flash developer, and I can't even publish to this dumb ipad i bought almost exclusively for this purpose. Please someone add something. I am actually quite good with as3. I try to use the mvc design pattern on all my projects. Also, if you help me get it working I promise to look at some of your posts or future posts to see if I can help you :)

Comment: da mit. I just realized this title sucks. I should have mentioned flash Pro CS6.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote; but I removed the 'flex' tag as this has nothing to do w/ the Flex SDK/Framework.  You can edit the title, or any content of your post by clicking the edit button on the tags under the question.  I modified your title. Is your problem with generating an IPA file?  Or with launching it on the device?  Are you trying to do both in one step?  The process of creating a formal release build in Flash Builder is known to take very long; I assume Flash Pro has similar issues.

Comment: Yes. The problem is creatingthe ipa file. It never finishes. I have to manually crash the program. Then when I try to use the ipa file by putting it into itunes it still doesnt sync right. I had thought it might be a real project that used the flex.swc but I guess not.

Comment: Do you have valid iOS Developer Certificates to build with? And Flextras is right. A standard build in FlashBuilder takes 5 minutes on my Quad Core i7 machine with 16GB RAM. On my older Core 2 Duo MacBook with 4GB RAM, it takes upwards of 30 minutes.

Comment: Yes I paid for the developer certificate and converted it to p12

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem eventually?